# Elasticsearch copy_to field type

Tags: elasticsearch

I wonder that if the type of destination field of ***copy_to*** must be ***text*** type.
I have not find the description in the official document.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html

In other words,can the ***full_name***'s type be other type but not text? Thanks.

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "first_name": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "full_name" 
      },
      "last_name": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "full_name" 
      },
      "full_name": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it yourself, I tried it creating with `keyword` and `integer` types and it worked perfectly fine.

However if you define it to be integer and then try to index text like the one given in example it will throw `mapper_parsing_exception`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
I actually tried it myself before asking the question. I found that when the ***new_full_name***'s type is specified as ***keyword***, the index can be created successfully, but no results were returned.
So,I wonder that is only the text type working well?

Comment: ```
PUT /copy_to_idx
{
  "mappings":{
    "properties": {
      "new_first_name": {
          "type":     "text",
          "copy_to":  "new_full_name" 
      },
      "new_last_name": {
          "type":     "text",
          "copy_to":  "new_full_name" 
      },
      "new_full_name": {
          "type":     "keyword"
      }}}
}

POST _bulk
{ "create" : { "_index" : "copy_to_idx", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "new_first_name" : "Peter", "new_last_name" : "Smith" }

GET copy_to_idx/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "new_full_name": "Peter Smith"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry for the ugly format,here  is the link of what I try :
https://github.com/ZhangDi-d/elasticsearch-demo/blob/main/copy_to.md

Comment: @xuelai, sorry for the delay in response, I looked at your github link which made the things clear to me, but reason why you are not getting result is due to the fact that you used keyword field to store `Peter` and `Smith` but If you just try with single field `first name` and `Peter`, it will show you the result. which means it works

Comment: @Ninja Thanks，I will spend some more time thinking about it，thanks.